# Horizontal scroll with mouse wheel at Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, scroll

I have a new mouse that has the ability to scroll right and left using its scroll wheel.
While this feature works on web pages, Photoshop and etc., it wouldn't do anything when I use it in the Visual Studio when looking at code that is longer (horizontally) than the window.

Is there a way to make it work?

Visual Studio is 2010 Express; the mouse is Logitech MX1100.

Comment: Can you email me (noahric at MS)?  I can forward you directly on to people who were working on hscroll mouse issues.

Comment: @Noah Richards: I have sent you an email using your blog. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues with horizontal scrolling in VS2010, some of which have been fixed or worked around after VS2010 shipped.  I'm not sure if the MX1100 is a specific example of any of the following, but some of the issues were/are:

1. Some mice drivers end up sending the event to the wrong HWND; we've seen cases where events will always be sent to the last-but-one thing focused, e.g. the solution explorer will scroll when the editor has focus. I think this one was *fixed*.
2. Many drivers, before sending WM_MOUSEHWHEEL (or faking WM_HSCROLL) check to see if the main HWND has WS_HSCROLL (declares it has a win32 horizontal scrollbar).  Since VS's main window doesn't, and things like the editor don't have **win32** horizontal scrollbars, they'll refuse to send horizontal scroll messages.  *This one is unfixed*.
3. (Definitely not your case, but) VMWare Fusion (on OS X) running windows doesn't forward on horizontal scroll events to the client OS.

I'll check with people to see if the MX1100 is known or falls into either of the first two categories.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. 1 and 3 aren't the issue in my case for sure. I have seen a problem with horizontal scroll scroll in Notepad++ as well. In this case the scrollbar seems to scroll visually but the code itself doesn't. In addition, the design of the scroll some why change it's color (from the blue of WinXP to gray)

Answer (score 54):

**EDIT** as *ShiftScroll* seems to have been abandoned, I created a small extension that adds this capability to Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drewnoakes.SideScroller

https://github.com/drewnoakes/vs-side-scroller

It enables scrolling in the text editor and several other panels such as the output window. Hopefully it helps someone out.

---

For VS2015 the *ShiftScroll* extension does this perfectly.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NGPearce.ShiftScroll

It scrolls left/right at a very comfortable speed while you hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

This would be a good built-in feature of VS IMHO.

Comment: Works well with vs 2017 as well. It is amazing.

Comment: We should not use comments in SO for thank yous, but... THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Unbelievable that this is not standard functionality.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution. Works well with VS Community 2019 Version 16.8.2

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll get this updated for VS2022 soon.

Comment: Works for me in VS 2022.

Comment: @avolkmann Especially considering VS doesn't allow the other typical behavior of clicking the scroll wheel to show the "compass thingy" that allows you to move the mouse in any direction to scroll.

Comment: Actually the ability to Shift+Scroll in the VS editor is now built in. It was added sometime around version 17.6 from memory. It doesn't work in Solution Explorer though (possibly a few other places), which my extension does, so I haven't excluded it from the newer versions.

Answer (score 4):

Try out my solution with AutoHotKey:

https://superuser.com/a/1144201/240650

```
; Shift + Wheel for horizontal scrolling
+WheelUp::
    ; Scroll to the left
    MouseGetPos,,,id, fcontrol,1
    Loop 8 ; <-- Increase for faster scrolling
        SendMessage, 0x114, 0, 0, %fcontrol%, ahk_id %id% ; 0x114 is WM_HSCROLL and the 0 after it is SB_LINERIGHT.
return
+WheelDown::
    ;Scroll to the right
    MouseGetPos,,,id, fcontrol,1
    Loop 8 ; <-- Increase for faster scrolling
        SendMessage, 0x114, 1, 0, %fcontrol%, ahk_id %id% ;  0x114 is WM_HSCROLL and the 1 after it is SB_LINELEFT.
return
```