# Is it possible to scroll horiztonally with keyboard/mouse wheel in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, navigation, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to scroll horizontally with the keyboard/mouse wheel in Visual Studio? I can do this via `Ctrl + Up` or `Ctrl + Down`, or just use the mouse wheel, for vertical scrolling, but I could not find out how to scroll left/right via Googling. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC.

**edit:** Just came across [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NGPearce.ShiftScroll), but it seems to be only compatible with VS2015. When I tried to use it with VS2017, it errored out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal scroll with mouse wheel at Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802175/horizontal-scroll-with-mouse-wheel-at-visual-studio)

Answer (score 2):

You need to go manage entension and search 'slideScroller' extension. Downloand and install. It's done. After then scroll horizontally with *shift+left Mouse*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to directly modify IWpfTextView.ViewportLeft for the active view. You can use the following two commands [Scroll the current text editor horizontally](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#hscroll) for my Visual Commander extension and assign to them shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign custom keybindings to the Edit.ScrollColumnLeft and Edit.ScrollColumnRight commands.  To do so:

1. Open Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
2. Show commands containing 'ScrollCol' (short enough to find these two)
3. For each command, set focus in the Press Shortcut Keys box and type your desired shortcut.
4. When you've found the keybinding you want, click the Assign button to save it.

In the image below you can see that I've set <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Right</kbd> to map to Edit.ScrollColumnRight, and <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd> is already assigned to the Edit.WordPrevious command when in the Text Editor.

[image: Example of setting a keybinding]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you click in the center button on the mouse and then navigate across?

Comment: I just tried this. Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me on VS2019.